Nvidia driver inconsistency between cards- Why don't I see newer drivers?
Ubuntu 24.04 with GTX 1080 sees nvidia-driver-560 as the newest, and 555, and many others.
My Ubuntu 24.04 with RTX3050 offers me nvidia-driver-535 as the newest option (I also see 470)

Probably a difference in the graphics-drivers PPA on the 1080 machine.
